# Checking every element of vector with functor

Tags: c++, vector, functor

I'm trying to detect whether every single element of the vector is fullfilling given condition, let's say it must even number.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 

bool isOdd(int i) 
{
    return i%2==0; 
} 

int main() 
{
   int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
   std::vector<int> myVec(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); 

   std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), 
   isOdd()); 

  // This piece of code is probably causing some problems; 

   while(myVec.empty()!=false) // while my vector IS NOT EMPTY 
   {
      std::cout << *it << " "; // print out the value of elements that 
                               // fullfiled the condition given in isOdd
   }                     

   return 0; 
}
```

What is wrong with my way of thinking ? Is the condition in while loop wrong or maybe I've completely missed the logic ?

Can you please provide me with some complex explanation of what is wrong with this piece of code ?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I know that there is a possibility to use lambda function instead, but I don't want to get too confused :)

Comment: `find_if` only returns the *first iterator* that fulfills the criteria

Comment: If you're using C++11, and you don't care to print out the odd values, then `std::all_of` with a predicate could have been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `find_if` returns the iterator pointing to the *first value* which meets the given condition. It stops there. You can put this in a loop to find *all* such elements, until it returns the *end iterator*.
2. The following line does the exact opposite of what you meant:

   ```
   while(myVec.empty()!=false) // while my vector IS NOT EMPTY
   ```

   Either write

   ```
   while(myVec.empty()==false)
   ```

   or

   ```
   while(myVec.empty()!=true)
   ```

   or simpler

   ```
   while(!myVec.empty())
   ```

You could write it as a for-loop:

```
for (auto it = find_if(begin(myVec), end(myVec), isOdd);
     it != end(myVec);
     it = find_if(it, end(myVec), isOdd))
{
    // do something with "it"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now I know what seems to be the problem, but I'm wondering whether I can stick to while loop, should I than modify it just by adding line 'it++' at the end ?

Comment: That's not going to work anyway. Your `while` loop condition has nothing to do with the state of the iterator, and if the vector is not empty at the start of the loop then that condition is never going to change while it executes. Your iterator will become invalid after `N` iterations, and your program will eventually crash.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your approach is that you are finding the odd number only once, and then for some reason you expect the vector to change, without making any modifications.

You should make a loop that calls `find_if` repeatedly, like this:

```
bool isOdd(int i) {
    return i%2!=0; 
}
... 
std::vector<int>::iterator it = myVec.begin();
for (;;) {
    it = std::find_if(it, myVec.end(), isOdd);
    if (it == myVec.end()) {
        break;
    }
    std::cout << *it << " ";
    ++it;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ffscwh)

Note: I changed your `isOdd` function to return `true` for odd numbers. The original version was returning `true` for even numbers.